# I want to use a SDI MFC to open a dialog and show a computed result in a edit control,but doesn't work

Tags: mfc

The problem is the edit box can't show the number “imgOutput.PixelCount(&imgInput).” but ‘0’.

Here is a modified version.

```
void CMyProgramView::OnPixelCount()
```

{

```
BeginWaitCursor();

CDlgPixelCount dlgPara;

dlgPara.DoModal();

EndWaitCursor();
```

}

…………

```
BOOL CDlgPixelCount::OnInitDialog()
```

{
    CDialog::OnInitDialog();

```
CMainFrame *pMain = (CMainFrame*)AfxGetMainWnd();   
CMyProgramDoc *pDoc = (CMyProgramDoc*)pMain->GetActiveDocument();

CImg imgInput = pDoc->m_Image;

CImg imgOutput = imgInput;

m_editPixelNumber = imgOutput.PixelCount(&imgInput);

UpdateData(false);

return TRUE;  // return TRUE unless you set the focus to a control
```

}

Problem still……

Comment: Calling UpdateData in the context of the view code does nothing for the dialog class.  The problem is likely in the dialog code.  Please post the dialog code, specifically, OnInitDialog ().

Answer (score 2):

The dialog controls do not exist until you call DoModal. So to put text into a dialog control you need two steps. First put the text into a dialog CString member variable, before DoModal. Then in the dialog class OnInitDialog the controls exist, so you can use SetWindowText or UpdateData to transfer the text into the control.

Comment: Can you show me what to do in OnInitDialog()?I am a newbie to MFC

Comment: There are several ways, depending on how you set up the m_editPixelNumber variable. What is its type and how is it initialized in DoDataExchange? You could search the net for an MFC tutorial and make progress a lot quicker.